# Deploy a laravel app to Azure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, azure

I have my application developed with Laravel 5.1 & MySQL. I don't know how to move it to Microsoft Azure.

Can anyone tell me how to deploy to Azure?

I am trying to figure out the costing too, but azure pricing calculator doesn't show MySQL & PHP in the list. Can anyone help with this too??

Thanks!!!

Comment: it will be listed as webapp + mysql

Comment: @Achraf Khouadja can you please tell me where can I find that option??? I am unable to find that

Comment: I am using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can leverage Azure Web Apps of Azure App Services to host your PHP applications. And the MySQL database service is provided by ClearDB on Azure. For dev or testing, they all provide free pricing tier.

- Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/partners/cleardb/databases/ for pricing plans of ClearDB on Azure.
- Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/ for App Service Pricing.

And you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-php-get-started/#create-a-php-laravel-app-on-your-dev-machine for steps of how to build and deploy a laravel application to Azure Web Apps.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.